# Codeigniter how to stop page reloading looping ? when i use session set_flashdata ? it going looping

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-flashdata

When I use CodeIgniter session `set_flashdata` and insert data in database page going looping infinity. but without use `set_flashdata` it working fine perfectly.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Successfully Inserted Settings');
redirect('admin/settings/sitesetting');
```

**autoload**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'email', 'session', 'encrypt', 'user_agent','pagination','Pdf');
```

**Controller**

```
public function sitesetting()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Admin - Site Settings';
    $data['setting'] = $this->AdminModel->selectalldata('tbl_settings');
    $set = $data['setting'];

    if(isset($_POST['submisetting'])){          

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('setting_text', 'Setting ', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $this->load->view('admin/setting',$data);

        }else{

            $value = $set[2]->id;

            $data = array( "setting_value"=> $this->input->post('setting_text'));

            $update = $this->AdminModel->updatedata('tbl_settings', 'id', $value, $data);                   

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Successfully Inserted Settings');
            redirect('admin/settings/sitesetting');             
        }   
    }else{
        $this->load->view('admin/setting',$data);
    }       
}
```

**Model**

```
function updatedata($table_name, $where, $id, $data){
    $this->db->where($where, $id);
    $this->db->update($table_name, $data);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `insert data in database page going looping infinity` explain this, Hence add full and Relevant code when adding question

Comment: @Vishal vasani can you check the set_flashdata at other controller so we can sure the set_flashdata is working for other controller. If working set_flashdata in other controller that means your controller have some logical issue in code Please show your view file also.

Answer (score 0):

$this->session->set_flashdata("success_msg", "Successfully Inserted Settings");
            redirect(''admin/setting',$data');

and then in view

session->flashdata('success_msg')): ?>
            
                ×
                session->flashdata('success_msg'); ?>